# Guest Printing on Chromebook?

Tags: printing, chromebook, guest-account

I have three chromebooks that will be used for guests. They need to all be able to print from one particular printer (HP Deskjet 3636) so that the users can print stuff from them. Is there any way to set this up so that anyone who comes by and decides to use our chromebooks will have the ability to print?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Cloud Print printer management screen at https://www.google.com/cloudprint#printers

Highlight a printer and click 'Share'.  Then click on 'Change' next to 'Private'.

You'll see the option there for link Sharing.  Choose that and then copy the link.  Email the link to whoever needs to print.

[Edit]  The above assumes you followed the printer's initial set up instructions to get it connected to Cloud Print.  If you didn't, go here: http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02817255